# Can not write the result in text file - C#

Tags: c#

I have the following code to extract 2 objects from each html page and save it in array. and finally write it in textfile. But I can not see the result in text file.

Thanks in  advance

```
for (int y = 0; y < 9; y++)
{
    if (IDs[y] == null)
    break;
    else
    {
        string item = Convert.ToString(IDs[y]);
        string url = "http://mu/tr/";
        string URL = url+item;
        WebClient web = new WebClient();
        String html= web.DownloadString(URL);
        MatchCollection m1 = Regex.Matches(html, @"<strong>\s*(.+?)\s*</strong>");
        MatchCollection m2 = Regex.Matches(html, @"<title>\s*(.+?)\s*</title>");
        foreach(Match m in m1)
        {
           string Gre = m.Groups[1].Value;
           string sic = m.Groups[2].Value;
           ITEM [y][0] = Convert.ToString(item);
           ITEM [y][1] = sic;
           ITEM [y][2] = Gre;
        }
     }
 }
 for (int row = 0; row < 9; row++)
 {
    for (int col = 0; col < 3; col++)
    {
        SIC.Write(ITEM[row][col] + " ");
    }
 SIC.WriteLine();
 }
SIC.WriteLine();
```

Comment: Have you single-stepped the code to see where the problem lies? Does your regular expression match actually produce results? Is there *anything* in the text file, like 9 blank lines? Is the program throwing an exception?

Comment: Thank you @JimMischel. YES It finds the matches that In find it by using break point. Also i am sure that there is any blank lines in textfile

Comment: What tis SIC? A StreamWriter? Where are you instantiating your writer and what's the path of the file you're attempting to write to?

Comment: @Sam. StreamWriter SIC = new StreamWriter(@"D:\DATA.txt");

Comment: As Jim Mischel already said: Start debugging, set a break point and single-step through your code. If you hover over your code, there should pop up informations about the vars. This way you could follow your grabbed text through your code and check where it gets lost (if it even gets grabbed the right way). I guess you would be much faster looking for the problem this way instead of writing the question and waiting for peoples to guess where it is.

Comment: @PedruJorge Do you have permissions to write to that directory? Try writing locally, such as `C:\Data.txt` as a test.

Comment: If it really is finding the matches and it's not throwing an exception, then most likely it's because you're not flushing the stream before you examine the file--probably because you're not closing the stream before exiting the program.

Comment: @JimMischel: I just tried it out myself. Writing a line and closing the app will save the written line anyway.

Comment: @C4ud3x: I just tested it. A console app that consists of `var sw = new StreamWriter("foo.txt");  sw.WriteLine("foo");` results in an empty file. Visual Studio 2013, .NET 4.5.

Comment: @JimMischel: Hmm ok. Looks like there's a difference somewhere. But to get back to topic: Better stay save and remember to close your stream. :)

Answer (score 0):

I can't comment because i don't have enough points but are you closing the stream writer and file when you are done?

If yeas and still no output debug the program. If all else fails open the stream write one test line and close. If the text is seen in the file then it is a problem in the for loop.

Comment: Haha. That was my first thought for this problem. But I just tried it out. The streamWriter doesnt has to be closed.

Comment: I thought that if the stream isn't closed whatever is in the buffer could get lost... and the file also gets locked for writing preventing other processes from using it.

Comment: I could get locked by the running process, thats right. WriteLine() will anyway save the line to the file.

Comment: When a process exits, the operating system will close any file handles that the process has open. So the file will not be locked. However, if you don't call `Close` on the `StreamWriter`, then it doesn't have the opportunity to flush its buffers and the underlying stream doesn't flush its buffers, either. The result is lost data. The simple program I described in my comment to the OP illustrates that.

Answer (score 0):

Check that your IIS process have enough permission to write in to this particular directory.

Comment: What makes you think that IIS is involved?